# Can I see previous "hot" questions from a particular SE site?

Tags: support

I want to see what questions has been "hot" for a specific SE site (in this case askubuntu).

I mean questions that managed to get into the top-left drop-down menu.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You mean other than going to that site and visiting the "Hot" tab?

https://askubuntu.com/?tab=hot

Comment: i mean questions that managed to get into the top-left drop-down menu .